# Trying to add fields to a javascript object

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, object, razor

I have a foreach loop (writen using MVC3's Razor engine) and I need to create a new object in the Popups array every iteration. Here's what I'm trying to run:

```
var popups = [];
var count = 0;

@foreach (var marker in Model) {
    <text>
    popups[count]["content"] = document.createElement("div");
    popups[count]["content"].class = "infobox-custom";
    popups[count]["content"].style.cssText = "padding: 5px; width: 600px;";
    popups[count]["content"].innerHTML = '<div class="professional"><h1>test</h1></div>';

    popups[count]["infobox"] = new InfoBox();

    popups[count]["marker"] = new MarkerInfo();
    count++;
    </text>
}
console.log(popups);
```

I'm getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'content' of undefined

As you can see, I'm trying to encapsulate each individual marker's related information in a javascript object. I'm aiming to access everything I need by using something like `popups[index].marker` or `popups[index].content`.

I'm reading the book Javascript: The Good Parts and there is one part that mentions:

> If the object does not already have that property name, the object is augmented:

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `popups[count]` to an object before you start adding properties to it.

```
var popups = [];
var count = 0;

@foreach (var marker in Model) {
    <text>
    popups[count] = {};
    popups[count]["content"] = document.createElement("div");
    popups[count]["content"].class = "infobox-custom";
    popups[count]["content"].style.cssText = "padding: 5px; width: 600px;";
    popups[count]["content"].innerHTML = '<div class="professional"><h1>test</h1></div>';

    popups[count]["infobox"] = new InfoBox();

    popups[count]["marker"] = new MarkerInfo();
    count++;
    </text>
}
console.log(popups);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `popups` an array of objects.

```
popups[count] = {}; // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<-----------------------------------
popups[count]["content"] = document.createElement("div");
popups[count]["content"].class = "infobox-custom";
popups[count]["content"].style.cssText = "padding: 5px; width: 600px;";
popups[count]["content"].innerHTML = '<div class="professional"><h1>test</h1></div>';
```